# How to use config variables in calendar/lib.php script in moodle 2.8

Tags: php, moodle

I am using moodle version 2.8

I want to use config variable in calendar/lib.php script

So how can I achieve this. Basically config.php is not included in calendar/lib.php script and I tried to

include it using "require_once('../config.php');", Showing blank page.

Answer (score 0):

The file calendar/lib.php is always included by a script that has already included config.php, so you do not need to include it yourself.

Just call

```
$val = get_config('core', '[nameofvalue]');
```

(where [nameofvalue] is replaced with the name of the config value you are after) to get the config value.

Alternatively, you can write:

```
global $CFG;
$val = $CFG->nameofvalue;
```